# EXC_BAD_ACCESS- crashes when going back on navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

So I'm stumped trying to find out why my program is crashing. So far, I have a home screen, which goes to a UITabBar with two tabs and each have UITableViews. On the second tab, I have a custom cell, and if the user clicks on it, the cell is supposed to give more details. All of this is in a UINavigationController. When I'm in the view controller with the table cell details, press back, and press back again (I should be on the home screen), the program crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1) here:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RaceMeAppDelegate class])); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS      }
}
```

From looking at other posts, I tried using the zombies instrument in Xcode to figure out where the problem was. I ran it, and it said "an objective-c message was sent to a deallocated "MatchCellDetailsViewController" object (zombie) at address 0x16f19370. The log looked like this:

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc  +1  1   00:14.422.351   UIKit   -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:]
1   Retain  +1  2   00:14.430.802   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
2   Retain  +1  3   00:14.431.402   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
3   Retain  +1  4   00:14.431.488   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
4   Retain  +1  5   00:14.431.977   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
5   Retain  +1  6   00:14.432.136   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
6   Retain  +1  7   00:14.432.310   Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:]
7   Retain  +1  8   00:14.432.639   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
8   Release -1  7   00:14.432.964   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
    Release (2) -2      00:14.433.013   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
10  Release -1  5   00:14.433.134   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
11  Release -1  4   00:14.433.176   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
12  Release -1  3   00:14.433.341   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
14  Retain  +1  3   00:14.434.055   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardSegue initWithIdentifier:source:destination:]
    Retain/Release (2)          00:14.434.138   RaceMe  -[ReceivedTabTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:]
17  Retain  +1  4   00:14.436.369   UIKit   -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:14.437.924   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:14.438.033   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Release (2)          00:14.438.158   UIKit   -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:14.465.975   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
25  Retain  +1  9   00:14.466.037   libsystem_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
26  Retain  +1  10  00:14.467.423   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
27  Autorelease         00:14.467.430   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
28  Retain  +1  11  00:14.467.467   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
29  Autorelease         00:14.467.475   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
30  Retain  +1  12  00:14.477.542   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
31  Retain  +1  13  00:14.484.362   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
32  Retain  +1  14  00:14.484.481   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
33  Retain  +1  15  00:14.484.582   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject addMappings:forCoder:]
34  Retain  +1  16  00:14.493.202   UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
    Retain/Release (12)         00:14.493.229   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
    Retain (4)  +4      00:14.494.155   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
40  Retain  +1  22  00:14.498.045   UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
46  Release -1  26  00:14.505.411   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
    Release (4) -4      00:14.506.686   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
    Release (4) -4      00:14.507.340   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
61  Release -1  11  00:14.509.718   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
62  Retain  +1  12  00:14.513.293   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
63  Autorelease         00:14.513.308   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
    Retain/Release (2)          00:14.513.330   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
66  Retain  +1  13  00:14.513.399   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
67  Autorelease         00:14.513.407   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
68  Retain  +1  14  00:14.513.477   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
69  Release -1  13  00:14.513.642   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:14.514.475   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
72  Retain  +1  15  00:14.719.975   libsystem_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:14.722.535   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Release (2)          00:14.723.110   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
77  Release -1  15  00:14.762.974   libsystem_blocks.dylib  _Block_release
    Release (3) -3      00:15.145.440   QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
84  Release -1  8   00:15.146.309   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
87  Release -1  5   00:15.147.134   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardSegue dealloc]
88  Release -1  4   00:15.147.183   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
89  Release -1  3   00:15.147.322   UIKit   -[UIStoryboardScene dealloc]
90  Retain  +1  4   00:15.385.010   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
91  Autorelease         00:15.385.017   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:15.429.329   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
94  Retain  +1  6   00:15.431.214   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
    Release (2) -2      00:15.431.373   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
97  Release -1  3   00:15.433.236   UIKit   __destroy_helper_block_119
98  Release -1  2   00:15.433.615   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:15.792.024   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:15.792.321   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (6)          00:15.792.807   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
    Retain/Release (2)          00:15.792.878   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:]
    Release/Retain (2)          00:15.792.899   UIKit   _popViewControllerNormal
    Retain/Release (2)          00:15.793.576   UIKit   _popViewControllerNormal
    Retain/Release (8)          00:15.824.455   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
124 Retain  +1  4   00:16.554.694   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
126 Retain  +1  4   00:16.555.120   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
128 Release -1  2   00:16.555.354   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
130 Release -1  0   00:16.559.291   UIKit   __destroy_helper_block_119
131 Zombie      -1  00:18.098.937   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
```

I tried seeing if I called MatchCellDetailsViewController somewhere where I wasn't supposed to, but I couldn't find where I used the class and would've caused the problem. The second tab is a delegate of MatchCellDetailsViewController so that I could pass data backwards, but other than that, I don't think I made any wrong calls. I'm not really sure what the _startCustomTransition is referring to.

Any help on locating where the problem could possibly be is appreciated. Thanks

**----EDIT----**

I think the problem is somewhere in these two classes and I tried posting the more relevant parts of the code.

ReceivedTabBarViewController.m (home screen goes to this)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.tableView reloadData]; //necessary to reload if user switches between tabs
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self loadMatchesWithCallback:^(NSArray *matches) {
    self.matches = matches;
    self.matchesMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.matches];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    if ([self.matches count] == 0) { [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating]; }

    for (GKTurnBasedMatch *match in self.matches) {
      //Gets the match data
      [self loadAndDisplayMatchDataWithCallback:match callback:^(NSData *matchData) {
        RaceMeGame *updatedGame = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];
        NSString *matchDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %d", updatedGame.matchDistance, updatedGame.status, updatedGame.score, updatedGame.numberOfTurns];
        [self.matchWithMatchData setObject:matchDataString forKey:match.matchID];

        NSLog(@"Match data: %@", matchDataString);
        NSLog(@"Current number of turns: %d", updatedGame.numberOfTurns);

        //Converts the matchID to a GKTurnBasedMatch
        [self retrieveMatch:match.matchID callback:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match) {

          GKTurnBasedParticipant *currentPlayerInMatch = [match currentParticipant];
          NSArray *currentPlayerIDs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:currentPlayerInMatch.playerID, nil];

          //Converts a player ID to a player's alias
          [self retrievePlayerAliases:currentPlayerIDs callback:^(NSArray *players) {

            [self.currentPlayerTurnAliasList addObject:((GKPlayer*)[players firstObject]).alias];

            if ([self.currentPlayerTurnAliasList count] == [self.matches count]) {
              [self.tableView reloadData];
              [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            }
          }];

        }];
      }];
    }
  }];
}

- (void)removeReceivedChallenge:(NSInteger)index
{
  GKTurnBasedMatch *match = [self.matchesMutable objectAtIndex:index];

  //Remove the data from table
  [self.matchWithMatchData removeObjectForKey:match.matchID];
  [self.matchesMutable removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index];

  NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myIP] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

#pragma mark - MatchCellDetailsViewController Delegate
- (void)indexRemoveViewController:(MatchCellDetailsViewController *)controller didFinishRemovingIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  [self removeReceivedChallenge:index];
}

- (void)moveChallengeToCurrentViewController:(MatchCellDetailsViewController *)controller didFinishMoving:(GKTurnBasedMatch*)match
{
  GlobalVars *globals = [GlobalVars sharedInstance];
  RaceMeGame *updatedGame = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:match.matchData];

  NSArray *currentPlayerIDs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:match.currentParticipant.playerID, nil];
  [self retrievePlayerAliases:currentPlayerIDs callback:^(NSArray *players) {

    [globals.currentMatches setObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]
                                       initWithObjectsAndKeys:updatedGame.status, ((GKPlayer*)[players firstObject]).alias, nil]
                               forKey:match.matchID];

    if (![globals.currentMatchesHelper containsObject:match.matchID]) {
      [globals.currentMatchesHelper addObject:match.matchID];
    }

  }];

}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowReceivedChallengeDetails"]) {
    MatchCellDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    long row = [myIndexPath row];

    //Distance-Status-Score-NumberOfTurns
    NSString *tempMatchString = [self.matchWithMatchData objectForKey:((GKTurnBasedMatch *)[self.matchesMutable objectAtIndex:row]).matchID];
    NSArray *tempMatchArrayData = [tempMatchString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    detailViewController.distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %@", [tempMatchArrayData objectAtIndex:0]];
    detailViewController.status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Status: %@", [tempMatchArrayData objectAtIndex:1]];
    detailViewController.participant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Current Players Turn: %@", [self.currentPlayerTurnAliasList objectAtIndex:row]];
    detailViewController.currentNumberOfTurns = [[tempMatchArrayData objectAtIndex:3] intValue];

    detailViewController.match = [self.matchesMutable objectAtIndex:row];
    detailViewController.rowSelected = (NSInteger)row;
    detailViewController.delegate = self;
  }
}
```

MatchCellDetailsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationController.delegate = self;
  self.distanceLabel.text = self.distance;
  self.statusLabel.text = self.status;
  self.currentPlayersLabel.text = self.participant;
}

- (IBAction)acceptInvite:(UIButton *)sender {

  [self.match acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
    }
    else {
      if (self.currentNumberOfTurns == 1) {
        //advance turn back to the other user
        [GameCenterHelper sharedInstance].currentMatch = match;
        NSLog(@"Advancing turn");

        /***** Preparation to advance turn ******/

        //Converting game to NSData and sending it as match data
        if ([[GameCenterHelper sharedInstance].currentMatch.matchData bytes] == 0) {
          NSLog(@"Match data not created yet, allocating and initializing it");
          [GameCenterHelper sharedInstance].gameData = [[RaceMeGame alloc] init];
          [[GameCenterHelper sharedInstance] advanceTurn];


          NSInteger index = self.rowSelected;
          NSLog(@"Index being passed: %d", index);
          [self.delegate indexRemoveViewController:self didFinishRemovingIndex:index];

          [self.delegate moveChallengeToCurrentViewController:self didFinishMoving:match];


        } else {
          [[GameCenterHelper sharedInstance] loadAndDisplayMatchDataWithCallback:[GameCenterHelper sharedInstance].currentMatch callback:^(NSData *matchData) {
            [GameCenterHelper sharedInstance].gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];
            [[GameCenterHelper sharedInstance] advanceTurn];


            //Remove this cell from ReceivedChallengesVC
            NSInteger index = self.rowSelected;
            [self.delegate indexRemoveViewController:self didFinishRemovingIndex:index];

            //Send the data to CurrentMatchesVC
            //Moves the challenge that the player has accepted the invite to from ReceivedChallengesVC to CurrentChallengesVC
            [self.delegate moveChallengeToCurrentViewController:self didFinishMoving:match];
          }];
        }

      } else {
        NSLog(@“Error: %@“, error);
      }
    }
  }];

}
```

Comment: add more code to this question

Comment: So you know what the problem is: somewhere you call a method on your ViewController after it's been deallocated. We can't really see where from the information you've given us.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I think the problem is somewhere in the two classes that I posted (I changed my layout of my UITabBar so that I don't go into the second tab and I don't really do anything in the view controller for the home screen.), which is the view controller for the table, and view controller for the details of the table's cell.

Comment: @Jon What do you do in `-[ReceivedTabTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:]`?

Comment: @ahruss Sorry, I made a mistake when typing out the class name. The method prepareForSegue is in the code above for ReceivedTabTableViewController

Comment: @ahruss Ah, I think you led to me to the correct answer. I'm not sure if it's the correct fix, but it doesn't crash anymore. In prepareForSegue, when I declared detailViewController as strong property instead, it doesn't crash. If you'd like to post the answer I can accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I found the actual answer. I found that the "fix" I made wasn't actually working when I started to do a different sequence of view controllers. It also looked weird so after looking at my code again, it looks like the actual problem was that I wasn't resetting my delegates.

Answer (score 2):

Swift iOS: Zombie UIKit [UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
I was using following code that was generating errors:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.delegate = self

}// end viewDidLoad
```

But once i have changed the delegate in view appear it started working without any crash

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't setting the delegate, it's resetting the delegate back to nil when the view controller is released.